# Toolbar and tablaout and fragment to share same background image

Tags: android

i am very new to android i am trying to display one background image to all my tool and tabs and fragment ,i got this background image to my toolbar and tab but how to show same background image to my fragment please any one help me how to do this 
my Xml code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:id="@+id/mainActivityBar"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="@drawable/actionbar"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="President"
        android:id="@+id/appname_1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        style="@style/myCustomTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appname_1"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/appname_1"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want like below image please any one help me how to get like below image 
[image]

Comment: Do you want the background image to shine through the toolbar? (Toolbar transparent?)

Comment: toolbar transparent, i need same image to tabs and viewpager ,thank u for ur quick reply@Desdroid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do the following:

Set the background of your `TabLayout` and `Toolbar` to transparent.
you can do that by this attribute: `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Then set the desired background image to your root view. (In your case its most probably a `CoordinatorLayout` - you didn't post the full layout).

If you need a code example let me know, but it should be pretty straightforward.

### EDIT:

As you requested a code example. It's just as I described above.
Instead of `CoordinatorLayout` as the root layout you can use of course any other layout you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/background">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
      <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: can you please send any source code example like @Desdroid

Comment: Have a look at my edit. Hope this is enough to help you.

Comment: i have a small doubt , when in case i need separate images on selected tab in that case what i should do @Desdroid

Comment: This basically is not part of your question, you should ask a new one. But already as an answer: You can set the background programatically as well. Just google for it.There are already numerous answers.

Comment: it working fine but when i use frame layout with in coordinate Layout it was not scrolling @Desdroid

Comment: Did you do any research on that? Frame Layout isn't for scrolling. You should use `NestedScrollView` within CoordinatorLayout.